# How to show a Popup in a ListModel (QML,Qt)

Tags: qt, qml

I am using QML to develope a GUI.

I have a ListModel as shown below in a file called List.qml:

List.qml

```
ListModel {
property string parentMenu

property variant sens: dids.sens //reading data

property string title: " LIST "
property bool showFunctions: true
property variant didsReadOnce: [
    "sens",
]



ListElement {
    type: "value"
    label: "sens"
    func1value: -128
    func1text: "DEFAULT"
    func3value: -1
    func3text: "!minus"
    func4value: 1
    func4text: "!plus"
    target: "dids.sens"
}
```

In this QML file, I want to popup a window when the sens value reaches 9 for example.

I tried to a put a Popup inside and outside the ListModel, but usually get Syntax Error.

My question is how can I show a popup in a ListModel using anyway, not necessarly Popup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to detect the number of items of your listmodel. You can use the onCountChanged signal. It the number is your maximum value show the dialog.

```
ListModel {
    id: model
    onCountChanged: {
        console.log("onCountChanged count:" model.count)
        if (model.count > MAX ) {
           dialog.visible = true
        }
    }
 }

Dialog {
    id: dialog
    width: 400
    height: 200
    visible: false
}
```

Comment: Thnk you for your reply, my problem now is that anything I put outside ListModel, gives me a Syntax error. If I put Popup, Text, Item it does not recognize this object, but if I put it inside the ListModel it is recognized. I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: @MahmoudHanafy could it be the `ListModel` is the root item? And the error is that a qml file cannot have more than one root item?

Comment: @Amfasis I am not sure, how can i know if ListModel is the root item? I am a bit new to QML, so I am not sure

Comment: It is basically the first item under the `import` statements (of course not comments ;-) ). Or in other words: the highest item in the hierarchy that you put in the file

Comment: Ahaa, maybe you are right, but how can i solve this and make it not a root item? should I put the ListModel in another object like Item or something?

Comment: @Amfasis I found also when I put Popup before the ListModel, Popup is recognized in this case but ListModel not (I mean by recognized is that it turns into green color and it is readable in the file) but if i put the Popup at the end, outside the list model, it is not readable, but ListModel is readable in theis case

Comment: @MahmoudHanafy Are you loading a list model from a file like this                                                                                  'ListView { model: MyModelFile {} }'  ? If yes, your dialog code and the handling of the signal "onCountChanged"should be at the main file (same as the listview). At your "MyModelFile.qml" file only put the ListElements.

Comment: @AdrianoCampos I have a qml file called ItemView.qml. in this file there is an object called ListView. In this LIstView something called onCountChanged.

So do you mean in my ListView object in ItemView.qml file I should put dialogue code

Comment: @AdrianoCampos I tried to put Dialog after ListView in ItemView.qml file like this:

ListView{}
Dialog{}
but Dialog is not recognized in the qml file, should i import anything?

Comment: Yes. try import QtQuick.Controls 2.4 or import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3.

Comment: @AdrianoCampos I have this problem when I import QtQuick.Controls 2.4 or  import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3, the screen on the panal just shows white without any data on it. Whta may cause this problem

Comment: @AdrianoCampos I tried to just put 
            console.log(listview.count)
under onCountChanged, but nothing even is printed in the console when i change the senstivity, why doe snot the console show any counts?

Comment: @AdrianoCampos sorry for my many comments, but now when i start the program it prents in the beginning like this:
OnCountChange is:  4
OnCountChange is:  0
OnCountChange is:  0
OnCountChange is:  0
OnCountChange is:  0
OnCountChange is:  0
OnCountChange is:  0
OnCountChange is:  0
OnCountChange is:  0

I dont know why 9 elements and what is 4?

Comment: @MahmoudHanafy What about share your source code by github or something else?